# Single User login Visual Basic Desktop application with MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I am looking for a way to create a visual basic desktop application that connects to a mysql database that I can monitor logins.  I want the user to only be allowed to be logged in at one location at a time.. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of concurrent connections for a single user:

`GRANT ... TO 'user'@'host' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 1;`

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//user-resources.html)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work..  The application needs to not let them login in two locations not the database connection. And where the application is not always connected only when a request is being made I don't see this working.